# How to get POST request data in WCF?

Tags: c#, angular, wcf, ionic-framework

I have an ionic application from which i need to insert a large string into the database by wcf service. I am sending the string in the Body of the POST request.

My angular method looks like this -

```
      uploadPic(bugImage : any)
        {    
    this.http.post("http://192.168.123.162/MyRestService/MyRestService.svc/ReportaBug", bugImage).subscribe(
            (data:any) => {
            console.log(data);
     }
   )
}
```

when i check the request into chrome's developer tools>Network, the request's status is OK but when i check the database, the string that is inserted is blank.

Here's my service code -

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method ="POST", UriTemplate = "/ReportaBug/base64String={base64String}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json )]
        void ReportaBug(string base64String);
```

how to get the data from the body in WCF? whatever string i am sending from my angular code, doesn't seem to get caught by the service. It just inserts blank string into the database. How do i get this working?

Comment: You may be confusing it by using the same value for the query-string and the name of the string of the method.  Change this " void ReportaBug(string base64String);" to " void ReportaBug(string myBody);" and see what happens.

Comment: "Operation 'ReportaBug' in contract 'IFusionRestService' has a UriTemplate that expects a parameter named 'BASE64STRING', but there is no input parameter with that name on the operation" i got this error after doing so.

Comment: I suspect your UriTemplate needs to be `UriTemplate = "/ReportaBug"`

Comment: Did that. Still nothing happening.

Comment: So, what is being send in the body then? Only that base64 string or is it wrapped in some JSON? Your dev console Network tab can tell you.

Comment: Just a string is being sent.

Comment: Still stuck! 
How to get this working?